# How to use higher-rank trait bounds to make a returned impl Fn more generic?

Tags: rust

I ran across Rust's higher-rank trait bounds recently and thought I could use them to make some functions in a parser I'm writing more generic.  However, a modification I've made is giving me an error message that I can't make heads or tails of.

Here's what I've got right now that works:

```
use nom::bytes::complete::is_not;
use nom::character::complete::multispace0;
use nom::combinator::verify;
use nom::error::{
    ParseError,
    VerboseError,
};
use nom::sequence::terminated;
use nom::IResult;

fn one_token<'a, E>(input: &'a str) -> IResult<&str, &str, E>
where
    E: ParseError<&'a str>,
{
    terminated(is_not(" \t\r\n"), multispace0)(input)
}

fn str_token<'a, E>(expected_string: String) -> impl Fn(&'a str) -> IResult<&str, &str, E>
where
    E: ParseError<&'a str>,
{
    verify(one_token, move |actual_string| {
        actual_string == expected_string
    })
}
```

This compiles.  However, my intuitions tell me that it's not necessarily great that the `impl Fn` I'm returning from `str_token` is bound by a lifetime parameter on `str_token`.  I believe having it that way could unnecessarily restrict the usefulness of the `impl Fn` trait that gets returned.  So I thought I could modify it to return an `impl Fn` that works for any lifetime `'b`, regardless of what the lifetime of the factory function `str_token_hrtb` is:

```
fn str_token_hrtb<'a, E>(
    expected_string: String,
) -> impl for<'b> Fn(&'b str) -> IResult<&str, &str, E>
where
    E: ParseError<&'a str>,
{
    verify(one_token, move |actual_string| {
        actual_string == expected_string
    })
}
```

Now, the compiler is giving me these errors:

```
error[E0277]: expected a `std::ops::Fn<(&'b str,)>` closure, found `impl std::ops::Fn<(&str,)>`
  --> src/main.rs:29:6
   |
29 | ) -> impl for<'b> Fn(&'b str) -> IResult<&str, &str, E>
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an `Fn<(&'b str,)>` closure, found `impl std::ops::Fn<(&str,)>`
   |
   = help: the trait `for<'b> std::ops::Fn<(&'b str,)>` is not implemented for `impl std::ops::Fn<(&str,)>`
   = note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'b> <impl std::ops::Fn<(&str,)> as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'b str,)>>::Output == std::result::Result<(&'b str, &'b str), nom::internal::Err<E>>`
  --> src/main.rs:29:6
   |
29 | ) -> impl for<'b> Fn(&'b str) -> IResult<&str, &str, E>
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter 'b, found concrete lifetime
   |
   = note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size
```

I don't understand how to read this.  Is it saying that the trait `for<'b> std::ops::...` is not implemented for the return value of `verify`?  If so, why not?  And why wouldn't the same issue exist for `str_token`?  Also, I can't find any way to interpret the second `type mismatch` error message.

Can anyone give some insight on what I'm doing wrong here and what the compiler is trying to tell me?

*Update*:

I'm using the nom parsing library found here: https://github.com/Geal/nom/

Also, the code for the `verify` function is here: https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/851706460a9311f7bbae8e9b7ee497c7188df0a3/src/combinator/mod.rs#L459

*Another Update*:

Decided to close this since I realized I may not have asked questions that were specific enough.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is indeed less than ideal. That's because not all difficulties of the [leak check step](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustc-guide/traits/hrtb.html#basic-matching-and-placeholder-leaks) of handling the hrtb lifetimes have been ironed out yet. Niko has been working on [it](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/65232) though.

If you turn off the leak check by pass `+nightly -Zno-leak-check` flag, you'll get a saner error message:

```
error: implementation of `std::ops::FnOnce` is not general enough
   --> src/main.rs:27:6
    |
27  |   ) -> impl for<'b> Fn(&'b str) -> IResult<&str, &str, E>
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `std::ops::FnOnce` is not general enough
    |
    = note: `impl std::ops::Fn<(&str,)>` must implement `std::ops::FnOnce<(&str,)>`
    = note: ...but `std::ops::FnOnce<(&'b str,)>` is actually implemented for the type `impl std::ops::Fn<(&str,)>`
```

Now, why does the compiler complain about `FnOnce` when you actually return `Fn`? This is me speculating but it should be reasonable. `FnOnce` is a super-trait to `Fn`, `rustc` is saying the code doesn't even satisfy the super-trait there's no way it could satisfy the more restrained trait itself.

This finally makes sense now. Consider the fact that [`verify`](https://docs.rs/nom/5.0.1/nom/combinator/fn.verify.html) is defined as:

```rust
pub fn verify<I: Clone, O1, O2, E: ParseError<I>, F, G>(
    first: F, 
    second: G
) -> impl Fn(I) -> IResult<I, O1, E> where
    F: Fn(I) -> IResult<I, O1, E>,
    G: Fn(&O2) -> bool,
    O1: Borrow<O2>,
    O2: ?Sized,
```

By asking it to be:

```rust
impl for<'b> Fn(&'b str) -> IResult<&str, &str, E>
where
    E: ParseError<&'a str>,
```

you're asking `forall<'b> 'b = 'a` which simply isn't possible.

---

Understanding how lifetimes work in Rust is very helpful and almost mandatory. When writing your own code though, it is better to skip them whenever possible. The lifetime elide rules are there to help you do exactly that. One certainly doesn't reach for hrtb lifetimes voluntarily :D

For example, the more idiomatic way to write your `one_token` and `str_token` functions could be:

```rust
fn one_token(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str>
{
    let res = terminated(is_not(" \t\r\n"), multispace0)(input)?;

    Ok(res)
}

fn str_token(input: &str, expected_string: String) -> IResult<&str, &str>
{
    let res = verify(one_token, |actual_string| {
        actual_string == expected_string
    })(input)?;

    Ok(res)
}
```

Comment: It's not just this example where I've encountered a need for HRTBs.  And I do understand lifetimes to some extent but, frankly, the feature and all its nuances are not very well documented at all.  For example, I've gathered that a lifetime variable specified as a generic type parameter on a function is generally bound at the call site of the function.  However, the binding behavior also seems to depend on the first variable in a function's parameters or return values that uses the lifetime.

Comment: For example, for `str_token`, I don't know if the lifetime parameter is bound at the call site of `str_token` or at the call site of the returned `impl Fn`.  It makes more sense to me that it would be bound at the call site of the returned `impl Fn`, but where's the documentation clarifying that this is in fact what happens?

Comment: Also, those examples you gave won't work for a couple of reasons.  Firstly, the `nom` library defines parsers generically as functions which always accept one parameter that is the input to be parsed.  So `str_token` as you define it can't be used with `nom`.  Also, I want my parsers to allow the caller to specify the error type with turbofish syntax at the call site of the parser.  This is the idiomatic pattern recommended by the authors of the `nom` library and I'd like to stick to it.  This necessitates the error type parameter and also the explicit lifetime on the input type that it wraps.